# Chrome Extension Content Script Never Run

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

**Hello, I am writing a simple chrome extension which will be used to:** 
 1. open new webpage
 2. fill timesheet form based on pasted string array
 3. submit timesheet (just clicking "ok" button in the form)
 4. open new webpage

**For this to work my extension needs to contain:**
 1. **popup.html** Browser Action popup, with *input textfield* for string array, and *submit button*.
 2. **timesheet.js** - javascript file to add logic to **popup.html**
 3. **background.js** - background page to take care of filling form, after clicking *submit button*
 4. **content_script.js** - to access newly opened webpage DOM, to fill the form.

For now, I made a simplified version, which is supposed to:
 1. open www.google.com in new tab
 2. wait few seconds (optionally, wait or page to finish loading)
 3. change background color

Everything seems to be woring fine, except for **content_script.js** listener doesn't react to message send by **background.js**

## Here is the code:

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Timesheet Filler",
  "description": "Description.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
        "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Timesheet Filler",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://www.google.com/*"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button id="btn" >Click Me!</button>
    <script src="timesheet.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**timesheet.js**:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    init();
});

function init(){
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.onclick = function() { onBtnClick(); }
}

function onBtnClick(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action:"btnClick"}, btnClickCallback);
}

function btnClickCallback(any){
    alert(any);
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(message.action == "btnClick"){
        chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.google.com", active:true});
        setTimeout(function(){ delayed(); }, 3000); 
    }   
});

function delayed(){
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, queryCallback);
}

function queryCallback(arr){
    var tabId = arr[0].id;

    console.log("message shown 3 second after clicking button") // THIS IS WORKING
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {action:"doSomething"}); // CONTENT SCRIPT DOESNT REACT TO THIS
}

function contentScriptCallback(any){
    alert(any);
}
```

**content_script.js**:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( message.action == "doSomething"){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor='#000000';  
        alert("do something");
    }
});
```

[Download all files in one ZIP here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-OftPVRoqqmM3ZBQ2l1bTBfUlE/view?usp=sharing)

How to make **content_script.js** react to to message and change webpage bg color?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: Google pages use `https` secure protocol, not `http` which you are specifying.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for noticing my mistake!

Indeed changing *content_script* and *permisions* URLs in my **manifest.json** fixed the problem! I've updated question with solution.

Comment: @deshu, nonono, this is wrong on stack* sites. Please rollback the edit and post it as an answer, then accept it.

Comment: @wOxxOm OK, sorry, I am new here. I've fixed it just now. I'll mark it as solution as soon as possible (two days from now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLUTION:

(thanks to @wOxxOm)

Content script wasn't called since `matches` in `content_scripts` section as well as `permisions` of **manifest.json** was defined wrong.
Easiest fix was to change URL range to: **`<all_urls>`**
*(for precise urls matches see [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns))*

**Fixed manifest.json**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Timesheet Filler",
  "description": "Description.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Timesheet Filler",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `all_urls` injects the content script on all sites that aren't related to google in any way, are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, since this extension is purely for personal purposes I don't mind. I've added link to developers guide, for anybody to find the way to specify precise urls.